# Null Reference error in Linq query doesn't go away even checking for null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have following query, "main" in query is a result from earlier steps.

```
var query = from a in main.AsEnumerable()
            join b in result on a.id equals b.tId into joint
            from c in joint.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new weekly()
            {
                id = a.id,
                Mon = a.Mon
                MHrs = (c.HoursList.Where(x => x.adt == "Monday")
                                   .Select(y => y.thr).FirstOrDefault())
           });
```

When I run this query I get `System.NullReferenceException` for MHrs. When I comment out the MHrs it runs fine.

I did try

```
y => y.thr == null ? null : 0
```

but it still didn't work.

Please let me know how to fix this query to run it without null reference exception. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you get NullReferenceException and not ArgumentNullException? It could be that HoursList collection is null.

Comment: Do you know if x.adt is null or y.thr is null? And y=>y.thr == null? null:0 should be as following: y=> y.thr == null ? 0 : y.thr

Comment: in c# default for reference type is _null_, so if `joint` is _Empty_, `c` is _null_

Comment: Error is: NullReferenceException and under Additional Information it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `DefaultIfEmpty`, `joint.DefaultIfEmpty()` will return null (default value of type) for non matching rows, so you will have to handle that:-

```
query= from a in main.AsEnumerable()
           join b in result on a.id equals b.tId into joint
           from c in joint.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new weekly()
            {
                id= a.id,
                Mon= a.Mon
                MHrs= c != null ? c.HoursList.Where(x=> x.adt=="Monday")
                                  .Select(y=>y.thr).FirstOrDefault() : ""
           });
```

Assuming `thr` is `String`.